# Factoring/approximating an apparently simple formula

Tags: arithmetic, induction, approximation, factoring

Does anyone know if the following formula can be factorized or approximated:

$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + a^2b + ab^2 + a^2c + ac^2 + b^2c + bc^2 + abc$

It looks a lot like $(a + b + c)^3$, except for the combinatorial factors.

Of course, the expression can be shortened as $\sum\limits_{x + y + z = 3} a^xb^yc^z$ but in terms of computational cost it does not help. This is a special case, I will have to use similar expressions with many more terms, but I believe that if someone could show me how to factorize/approximate this one, I can adapt it to the following more general case:

$\sum\limits_{|\vec{\alpha}|=n}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_j^{\alpha_{j}}$ with $\vec{\alpha}$ an n-dimensional multi-index ($\vec{\alpha} = \{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}$, with $\alpha_i$ non-negative integers.).
(sorry if the mathematical notation is wrong).

Is there a way to approximate the result? Probably it can not be factorized nicely, but surely there is a way to approximate it with something less resource-consuming.

Thank you!

edit: If it helps, $0< a < b < c \leq 1$, and $0 < a_1 < ... < a_n < 1$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialSeries.html

Comment: Nope, here I don't have the combinatorial factor $\dbinom{n}{\vec{\alpha}}$ that you have in multinomial series

Comment: What about $(a+b+c)^3 - 2(a+b+c)*(ab+bc+ca)$? Note the re-use of $(a+b+c)$ so it needs to be computed only once. In general, looking into [symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) might provide some ideas. What is your computational model (i.e. what operations are "expensive" if the direct evaluation is too difficult)?

Comment: Alright, I gave a look at symmetric polynomials. More specifically this is a complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial. So thank you for that, I'll see if there are interesting properties in there. The computational model does not really matter, the problem here is that as n increases the number of operations to perform increases exponentially. I may have to use values of n up to one thousand so bruteforce calculation is not really an option here. I simply hope there is an approximation that would not increase that much in complexity with higher values of n

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{|\alpha|=n} \prod_{j=1}^k a_j^{\alpha_j} = S(n,k)$ where $S(n,0) = 0$ and
$$S(n,k+1) = S(n,k) + a_{k+1}^n + \sum_{p=1}^{n-1} a_{k+1}^p S(n-p,k)$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what is $S(n - p)$. Isn't S defined on $\mathbb{N}^2$?

Comment: Robert, you might want to fix the second $\sum$ in definition of $S(n,k)$, I believe it should be $\prod$.

Comment: @user119260 It was apparently supposed to be S(n−p,k) (the S(n,k) quantity represents sum of complete homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ of first $k$ variables)

Comment: @PeterKošinár Yes, thanks (I'll edit)

Answer (score 2):

For the order one case the sum will be:

$$\sum a_j $$

For the order two case the sum will be:

$$\frac12 \left(\sum a_j \right)^2 + \frac12 \left(\sum a_j^2  \right)  $$

For the order three case the sum will be:

$$\frac16 \left(\sum a_j \right)^3 + \frac12 \left(\sum a_j \right)\left(\sum a_j^2  \right)  + \frac13 \left(\sum a_j^3 \right)$$

For the order four case the sum will be

$$\frac1{24} \left(\sum a_j \right)^4 + \frac14 \left(\sum a_j \right)^2\left(\sum a_j^2  \right) + \frac18 \left(\sum a_j^2  \right)^2  + \frac13 \left(\sum a_j \right)\left(\sum a_j^3 \right)+ \frac14 \left(\sum a_j^4 \right)$$

and there will be similar expressions for higher orders.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, similar to **Robert Israel**'s, is also based on the quantity $$S(n,k)=\sum_{\begin{eqnarray}(c1,c_2,\ldots,c_k)\in\mathbb{N}_0^k\\ c_1+c_2+\ldots+c_k = n\end{eqnarray}}\ \prod_{j=1}^k a_j^{c_j}$$ which corresponds to complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial of degree $n$ in variables $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$. The recurrence is different, though:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
S(0,k) & = & 1\\
S(n+1,0) & = & 0 \\
S(n+1,k+1) & = & S(n+1,k) + a_{k+1}\cdot S(n,k+1)
\end{eqnarray}$$

This permits calculation of $S(n,k)$ in $O(nk)$ time and using $O(k)$ memory:

```
S[0] = 0
for(int k=1; k<=K; k++) S[k] = 1
for(int n=1; n<=N; n++) for(int k=1; k<=K; k++) S[k] = S[k-1] + a[k]*S[k]
return S[K]
```

If $n$ was considerably bigger than $k$, one could compute the result using matrix powers. Let 
$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_1 & a_1 & \ldots & a_1 & a_1 \\
0 & a_2 & \ldots & a_2 & a_2 \\
\vdots & & & & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{k-1} & a_{k-1} \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & a_k \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Then, $$(1,1,1)\times A^n = \left(S(n,1),S(n,2),\ldots,S(n,k)\right)$$ (the matrix $A$ implements one iteration of the recurrence). Computing $n$-th power of matrix by repeated squaring can be done in $O(\log n)$ steps, with each step consisting of one matrix multiplication.